# Laravel flash message validation

Tags: laravel

I am creating a CRUD of books and what I wanted to do is like the generated `auth` files that if someone registers and didn't input any in the textbox, a flash message will return. I am doing that now in my crud but I can only make a flash message when a book is successfully created. This is my store function

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'isbn' => 'required|',
        'title' => 'required',
        'author' => 'required',
        'publisher' => 'required'
    ]);
    Session::flash('msg', 'Book added!');
    $books = $request->all();
    Book::create($books);
    return redirect('books');
}
```

And in my home.blade.php

```
@if(Session::has('msg'))
<div class="alert alert-success">
 {{ Session::get('msg') }}
 </div>
 @endif
```

This actually works but I want to show some ready generated error flash when someone didnt complete fields. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty simple, first there's a sweet nice feature that is the `redirect()->with()`

So your controller code could be:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'isbn' => 'required|',
        'title' => 'required',
        'author' => 'required',
        'publisher' => 'required'
    ]);
    if(Book::create($books)){
      $message = [
        'flashType'    => 'success',
        'flashMessage' => 'Book added!'
      ];
    }else{
      $message = [
        'flashType'    => 'danger',
        'flashMessage' => 'Oh snap! something went wrong'
      ];
    }
    return redirect()->action('BooksController@index')->with($message);
}
```

Then on your view:

```
@if (Session::has('flashMessage'))
  <div class="alert {{ Session::has('flashType') ? 'alert-'.session('flashType') : '' }}">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    {{ session('flashMessage') }}
  </div>
@endif
```

**Bonus** you can put this on your footer, so the alerts boxes will vanish  after 3 seconds:

```
<script>
  $('div.alert').delay(3000).slideUp(300);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could get the individual errors for a field

```
{!! $errors->first('isbn'); !!}
```

or you can get all the errors

```
@foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
     <div>{{ $error }}</div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: How can I implement this with a controller?

Comment: Didn't understand what you meant by "implement this with a controller". I see that you are already validating data inside your controller. Above code is used to display errors.

Comment: I'm starting with slimframework for now again. Can I use slim framework for now because I don't have any big projects for now? Just simple projects :)

Comment: Yes, you can use Slim for small projects.

Answer (score 1):

you can use try catch like this

```
try{
$books = $request->all();
Book::create($books);
Session::flash('msg', 'Book added!');
}
catch(Exception $e){
Session::flash('msg', $e->getmessage());
}
```